# Ubuntu 18.04 Keystroke Alt + Shift + (Ctrl) + Down does not work

Tags: unity, 18.04, shortcut-keys

After upgrade from Ubuntu 16.04 LTS to 18.04 LTS (with unity) the keystrokes `Shift + Alt + Down` and `Alt + Shift + Ctrl + Down` stopped working (btw `Alt + Shift + (Ctrl) + [Up, Left, Right]` works).
I used these keybindings in PHPStorm/Webstorm. In these programs you can search what a key binding does by simply pressing those keys and when I do, Webstorm does not display/catch these keystrokes, like if they were not pressed.
I searched in CompizConfig Settings Manager advanced search in settings value, in the Settings/Keyboard/Shortcuts and with `gsettings list-recursively | grep Down` and I didn't find anything.
If I press this combo outside of Webstorm Ubuntu does nothing.
Have you any idea where this keybinding could be saved?

PS: I tried this [tool (screenkey)](https://github.com/wavexx/screenkey) to display pressed keys. But it didn't display `Alt + Shift + Down` or `Alt + Shift + Ctrl + Down`

Thank you for your help

Comment: seems latest ubuntu remaps super key... I had similar problem... perhaps solution here can help you: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033219/alttab-stopped-working-in-upgrade-to-18-04

Comment: @JoshuaBesneatte Thank you for your reply, but this is not that case. But I looked on the `Switch applications` option and I have this option as disabled, but pressing `Alt + Tab` switches applications, which is weird

Comment: The `Alt + Tab` is defined in ccsm, my bad

Comment: This should help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74408842/9158604

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After deeper investigation I found out, that this issue is a hardware keyboard problem.
I tried this keystroke on windows and it also was not recognized.
I have Roccat Isku keyboard.
At work I tried the same upgrade from 16.04 to 18 and replacing gnome with unity and this keystroke worked (I have different keyboard at work)

Answer (score 12):

Gnome Tweaks helps me to fix it!

1. Go to *Keyboard & Mouse > Additional Layout Options*.
2. Turn off all options for "Switching to another layout".

   [image: Gnome Tweaks layout switching options]

Comment: It did the trick on Ubuntu 20.04. Thanks a lot!

Comment: The same for U 20.04. Had issues with IntelliJ IDEA hotkeys.

Comment: In my case "Switching to another layout" section was all unchecked, in Settings — Keyboard shortcuts "move workspace" was set to Super+Page up\down, but workspaces still changed by ctrl+alt+up\down. When I *checked*  `Alt+Ctrl` in "Switching to another layout" section — then Alt+Ctrl+Down\Up **stopped** working. But this broke all my key bindings involving alt and ctrl in other programs.  Weird. I remapped "move workspace" in general key settings to ctrl+alt+up\down and then back to Super+Page up\down and ctrl+alt+up\down combination became free as needed. Weird.

Comment: You saved my life! I had the same issue in Android Studio & IntelliJ IDEA after upgrading Ubuntu from 18.04 to 20.04. I have just disabled all options in "Switching to another layout" and all shortcuts are working again!

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue recently, while trying to use this keys combination inside vscodium, in Ubuntu 20.04

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>up</kbd> or <kbd>down</kbd> not working as I entend, since it changes the working space instead of the expected function inside a code editor

### First approach

Trying to fix it through:

1. Activities > Setting > Keyboard Shortcuts
2. Navigation > Move to workspace above/bellow

**didn't work** either, because this keys combinition: ctrl + shift + alt + up/down, doesn't show there

### Solution

1. install dconf-editior

   ```sh
   sudo add-apt-repository universe # active by default, but just in case
   sudo apt update
   sudo apt install dconf-cli dconf-editor
   ```
2. go to:

   ```
   /org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings/move-to-workspace-down
   ```
3. disable **Use default value**

[image: disable: Use default value]

4. edit **Custom value**: by removing

   ```
   <Ctrl><Shift><Alt>Down
   ```

[image: edit: Custom value]

5. Apply
6. follow the same steps for Up (instead of Down)

   ```sh
   /org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings/move-to-workspace-up
   ```
7. log out/in

### Result

- you are able to use/bind the keys combinition to whatever you need, (if the editor support it ...)
- you don't lose the workspace navigation feature, since it's still keybond by default to
  `<Supper><PageUp>` and `<Supper><PageDown>` for workspace up and down. and you can actually change this shortcuts, from the keyboard shortcut settings

---

- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Keybindings
- https://askubuntu.com/a/575482
- https://askubuntu.com/a/1131849

Comment: Thanks, really helpful. **not just for Ubuntu**, works on all gnome based desktops

Comment: It works fine on GNOME on UBUNTU 22.04.3 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish). Thanks a lot.

Comment: You saved my day!!!! Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 3):

In my case it luckily was just about re-mapping the keys in Settings->Keyboard->Shortcuts.

Here, moving the active window up/down was defined as Shift+Super+Page Up/Down, same without Shift was applied for moving one workspace up/down.

Re-mapping to what I was used to ([Shift+]Ctrl+Alt+Up/Down) did the trick :-)

Answer (score 3):

For Gnome Shell, the workspaces stand in the way. Even the keyboard shortcuts differ a bit to Phpstorm (in my case there was the `shift` modifier which was not part of the Gnome shell shortcut binding), the workspace up/down block the keybindings in Phpstorm.

So for Gnome Shell, disable dynamic workspaces:

```
$ dconf write /org/gnome/mutter/dynamic-workspaces false
```

Set the number of (now static) workspaces to one:

```
$ dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/wm/preferences/num-workspaces 1
```

Disable the up/down keyboard shortcuts which are blocking Phpstorm:

```
$ dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings/switch-to-workspace-up "['disabled']"
$ dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings/switch-to-workspace-down "['disabled']"
```

These fixes are keyboard independent and I can confirm not doing so will have the hotkeys `Ctrl+Alt+Shift+Up`, `Ctrl+Alt+Shift+Down`, `Ctrl+Alt+Up` and `Ctrl+Alt+Down` not working in Phpstorm as the Gnome Shell blocks them.

I just stumbled over the issue and also kept note in my blog ([Gnome Shell Quickfix Cheatsheet](https://hakre.wordpress.com/2019/04/07/gnome-shell-quickfix-cheatsheet/)).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on Zorin OS. Neither of these helped. I have the G613 Keyboard and I've tested the keys. Even though some of them are not recognized, <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd> are.

What helped me was to check the *Switching to another layout Alt+Shift* checkbox in the Gnome Tweaks tool under the *Additional Layout Options* submenu of the *Keyboard & Mouse* menu.