# What is hiding Ctrl + Shift + Alt + Up/Down

Tags: gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys

I'm using Pycharm as an editor and wish to use the *next change* keyboard shortcut, which is Ctrl+Shift+Alt+Up/Down. However it does not register. It even seems to not register just Ctrl+Alt Up/Down.

What are those shortcuts bound to in Gnome?
I could fix the left and right with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50373094/184379)
and I tried [Gnome Tweaks](https://askubuntu.com/a/1108386/141011), but nothing works.

On 19.4

Comment: What about "up" and "down"? (switch-to-workspace-up and switch-to-workspace-down)

Comment: @vanadium that didn't work :(

Comment: `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-down "['<Super>Page_Down']"` will disable the assignment of Ctrl+Alt+Down to Gnome Shell, but keep the alternative default key binding. If it then still does not work in Pycharm, you will have to look in Pycharm to find the problem.

Comment: [Link to JetBrains ticket](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206868075-Ubuntu-eats-my-shortcuts-Ctrl-Alt-Shift-Up-Down). But suggestions there didn't resolve the issue for me yet (however, I'm using Gnome on Fedora).

Answer (score 2):

It [finally worked](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206868075-Ubuntu-eats-my-shortcuts-Ctrl-Alt-Shift-Up-Down?page=1#community_comment_10196831748242) for me:

- Instead of simply disabling `Ctrl + Shift + Alt + {Up|Down}` shortcuts in the actions where they originally belong to (moving window across workspaces),
- Try assigning `Ctrl + Shift + Alt + {Up|Down}` to something irrelevant like "Volume up" and "Volume down",
- Then delete them from "Volume up" and "Volume down".
- Now GNOME will finally think shortcuts are unassigned (and IDEA, in my case, were able to receive events).

Comment: This worked only for a short period of time for me. After reboot or lock, the shortcut stoped working in my ide.

Answer (score 1):

Running these seems to work immediately:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-up '[]'
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-down '[]'
```

The resulting [NixOS configuration](https://gitlab.com/engmark/root/-/merge_requests/404/diffs?commit_id=9d22f77cd3000014bb95b2f5dab425e6d42c103a) might also be useful to someone.

Comment: Verified on Ubuntu 23.10 and Intellij 2023.2.4