# What is hiding Ctrl + Alt + Windows + Up/Down in IntelliJ on Ubuntu

Tags: 22.04, intellij

I am trying to assign the keyboard shortcut `ctrl + alt + windows + down` to a specific editor command in IntelliJ but it is not working.

In the process of adding the shortcut combination I hold down the keys 1 at a time and IntelliJ shows me the following to indicate what I am pressing:

| Keys I'm holding | What IntelliJ thinks I'm holding |
| --- | --- |
| `ctrl` | `ctrl` |
| `ctrl`+`alt` | `ctrl`+`alt` |
| `ctrl`+`alt`+`windows` | `ctrl`+`alt`+`windows` |
| `ctrl`+`alt`+`windows`+`down` | `ctrl`+`alt`+`down` |

I'm not sure why, in the last step, the Windows key suddenly disappears?

I've seen others suggest in [similar cases](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1193089/what-is-hiding-ctrl-shift-alt-up-down?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C184.8671) that there is a conflicting Gnome shortcut which can be unset with something like:

`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-down '[]'`

However, I checked that and there were no conflicting shortcuts I could see.

`gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings`

I'm not sure what else to check next, any ideas?

FYI, this key combination works in other IDEs like Visual Studio Code, so this may be an IntelliJ thing.

- Ubuntu: 22.04.1-Ubuntu
- IntelliJ: IntelliJ IDEA 2023.2.5 (Community Edition)

**Update**
Also I can't seem to map `windows`+`down` either. I remove it from a conflicting setting in gsettings but it still doesn't work in IntelliJ

Answer (score 0):

Man that wasted a lot of my time :(

I discovered that there are a bunch of people suffering similar problems in the Intellij support system.

Anyway, what is working for me now is to add a setting to your custom properties file which makes the IDE recognise the windows (super) key properly.

`Help –> Edit Custom Properties... –> keymap.windows.as.meta=true`

It does say 'use at your own risk' [where I found the advice](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-144702/Unable-to-use-Windows-as-a-modifier-key-in-keymap#focus=Comments-27-1491339.0-0) but I'm more at risk of throwing my computer out of the window ha ha.