# How to use shift+alt+arrow-down for copy the selected lines just under the selected lines in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, html5, css

Previously I used Windows 10 operating system. I am a beginner and I am learning HTML, CSS. I used Visual Studio Code on Windows 10. There I used the `shift + alt + arrow-down` key to duplicate some selected lines just under the selected lines. I recently shifted to Ubuntu and the `shift + alt + arrow-down` key is not working like windows. It is not duplicating the selected lines.

How can I make these keys working like windows or is there any other key to do the same work?

Help me, please.

Answer (score 3):

On Linux you have to hold Ctrl as well.  `Ctrl + Shift + Alt + Down`

Linux software often avoids key combinations that use Alt on its own because Linux desktops often capture the Alt key for other uses.

Comment: It is not working. It is creating new workspace.

Comment: Oh ok.  It is working for me on Linux.  In your case, open Preferences -> Keyboard shortcuts and search for the entry for "Copy Line Down".  There it will list which shortcut is currently set for this action, if there is one, and you can even modify it.

Comment: gnome desktop users should do this solution [askubuntu.com/a/1378045](https://askubuntu.com/a/1378045)